# There’s a cat5e coming out of my wall, how do I make it work?

Tags: data-wiring, ethernet

I recently moved in with family and noticed a Ethernet cord coming out of the wall in my room (mine is the only room with one). It’s obviously not connected to the modem or router, and I’m not sure where the other end is. The pictures linked are the only places I’ve found that it could go. EDIT: okay, it definitely connects to the surge protector outside. It doesn’t seem necessary since it’s not currently in use. That being said, can I connect it to the router instead and use the Ethernet?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIVHf.jpg

Comment: Of the two pictures you’ve provided, the top one is of an Ethernet surge protector (Motorola 600SS), typically used to remove surge risk from outdoor radio equipment that provides wireless internet. One cable will normally come in from an outdoor access point or point-to-multipoint radio.  The other would typically go to either a firewall or a switch to distribute internally.  (Your second photo is coax cable used for cable TV and unrelated.) If you want to try to trace the cable in your wall, you’ll need either to find the other end and see if it connects to this or use a Toner & Probe.

Comment: I’ve traced the cable in my room and determined that it does indeed run to this surge protector. 1. Is it necessary if it isn’t connected to anything? 2. Can I connect it to the router instead?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be hard to tell without more info (e.g. what's it doing running to the surge protector).

Answer (score 0):

The larger box is standard CATV hookup. A number of those cables coming out of the larger box probably go to different rooms for cable TV. One of those cables could provide internet but it would have to terminate in a router/modem where the cat 5e cable would originate and then run to different outlets. Get with the cable company serving the area. It looks like a Comcast system and not an ATT Uverse.